# Postgresql request to get recommended friends

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, friends and relations of friends:
Friendship is **symmetrical**.

```
CREATE TABLE t_users (
user_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE t_friendship (
friendship_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
from_user_id varchar,
to_user_id varchar
);

INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us123', 'us123');
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us456', 'us456');
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us789', 'us789');
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us987', 'us987');
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us654', 'us654');
INSERT INTO t_users VALUES ('us321', 'us321');

INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr123', 'us123', 'us456');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr456', 'us123', 'us789');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr789', 'us123', 'us987');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr987', 'us456', 'us123');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr654', 'us456', 'us321');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr321', 'us987', 'us123');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr322', 'us456', 'us654');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr323', 'us654', 'us123');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr324', 'us789', 'us654');
INSERT INTO t_friendship VALUES ('fr325', 'us321', 'us123');
```

How to make a request to get recommended friends.
For example friends of my friends.

Thank you.

Comment: Join `t_friendship` with itself to get the friends of friends.